# Using titan graph db with c# and gremlin

Tags: c#, gremlin, titan

That was so hard to install it. I want to use Berkeley + Elastic Search configuration.
I dont know it is production ready. Rexter seems good communication Layer. I can start titan server (?) via secret

```
g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/titan-local');
```

command. The location of db is C:\tmp\titan-local. How can I communicate it with c# + gremlin remotely?

PS: I had to choose it because of gremlin support. If they dont give up the project -with elastic search support-  -gremlin compliant- it looks like so promising..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titan is used in a number of production environments, though as of today, Elastic Search integration in 0.3.0 is still considered "experimental".  A 0.3.1 release will be released to harden these latest features.  If you want to use C# your best option at this time is to use Rexster with one of these two options:

https://github.com/dkuppitz/rexpro-client
https://github.com/inthefabric/RexConnect

Comment: I can connect Titan via RexproClient..There is only one question is Titan production-ready?

Comment: stephen do you have any idea for titan 0.3.1 release date?

Comment: should be any day now.  please watch the aurelius-graphs mailing list for the official announcement.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aureliusgraphs